# LINQy way to check if any objects in a more than one collection have the same property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three collections of the same model, only changing their names.

want to check the three lists so that:

1) If an element in either list is already in another burst an error
2) When I try to validate the Any does not accept null value.
How do they accept that the string is null?

but I can not.

where I am going wrong?

`item.Requeridos` > `ICollection<MeetingUser>` 
`item.Informados` > `ICollection<MeetingUser>` 
 
`item.Opcionais` > `ICollection<MeetingUser>`

```
public static ValidationResult validaUsuariosNaLista(Reuniao item)
{
    var requeridos = item.Requeridos.Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Login)).Any();
    var informados = item.Informados.Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Login)).Any();
    var opcionais  = item.Opcionais .Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Login)).Any();

    if (item.Requeridos.Count() + item.Informados.Count() + item.Opcionais.Count() > item.Requeridos.Concat(item.Informados).Concat(item.Opcionais).Distinct().Count())
    {
        return new ValidationResult(Resources.Validations.sameUserInOtherList);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where I am going wrong?

In the way that `Distinct` works. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The Distinct(IEnumerable) method returns an
>   unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values. It uses the
>   default equality comparer, Default, to compare values.
>
> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. **To
>   compare a custom data type**, you must implement this interface and
>   provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

In your case you have a custom data type, `MeetingUser`

> What can you do?

If you avoid the use of `Distinct`, you can try something like the below:

```
// Initially you concat the three list to one list
var combinedLists = (item.Requeridos.Concat(item.Informados)).Concat(item.Opcionais);

// Then you group them by the Login. If there is any group with more that 1
// element then you have the same login more that one time.
var result = combinedLists.GroupBy(x=>x.Login)
                          .Any(gr=>gr.Count()>1);
```

Otherwise, if you stick with the `Distinct`, you have to implement the `IEquatable` interface.

Comment: Amazing.. but I still have a problem.
the Any does not miss if the field is null :(. tks so much

Comment: You could filter your sequences, using a `Where`, `item.Requeridos.Where(x=>x.Login!=null)`.

Comment: Is `Option 2` really an option? Am I the only one thinking it is not equivalent to `Option 1`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I suggested another LINQ operator there. In this perspective, I think that this is another option. I might be wrong in the way I stated it :(

Comment: But isn't it the same problem as Distinct? I mean, it's not accounting for a property like option 1, no?

Comment: Oops you are bloody correct ! My wrong...Thanks I will correct correspondingly my answer.

Comment: I try "where", but still yes it for the mistake. ( Value cannot be null) about problem 2

Comment: So, `combinedLists` contains `MeetingUser` objects with null `Login`?

Comment: `item.Opcionais` the rule is that it can be null.
When you do not put any value on it shows the error
`"Value can not be null."`
Is there any way to let him pass null?

Comment: I got it...Yup, you can. Try this `item.Opcionais ?? Enumerable.Empty<MeetingUser>()`.

Comment: I try `item.Opcionais.Select(x => x.Login) ?? Enumerable.Empty<ReuniaoParticipante>();` does not worked, also tried `.Where and .any.` 
not only I tried what u wrote because he must select the Login, right?

Comment: `var combinedLists = (item.Requeridos.Concat(item.Informados)).Concat(item.Opcionais ?? Enumerable.Empty<MeetingUser>());`

Comment: This is what I meant. Notice that in the last `Concat` we pass the `item.Opcionais`, provided that is not null. Otherwise we pass an empty sequence of `MeetingUser` objects. Please try this one and let me know.

Comment: Very good. I will answer the question ended with the resolution of the answers. Tks you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:

if the object can also be null use `item.Opcionais` as example

Tks **@Christos** so much.
 
Yours answers were very good

```
public class ReuniaoValidation
    {
        public static ValidationResult validaUsuariosNaLista(Reuniao item)
        {
            var requeridos = item.Requeridos.Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Login)).Any();
            var informados = item.Informados.Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Login)).Any();
            var opcionais = item.Opcionais ?? Enumerable.Empty<MeetingUser>();

            var listasCombinadas = (item.Requeridos.Concat(item.Informados)).Concat(item.Opcionais ?? Enumerable.Empty<MeetingUser>());

            if (listasCombinadas.GroupBy(x => x.Login).Any(gr => gr.Count() > 1))
            {
                item.AddOdm = false;
                return new ValidationResult(Resources.Validations.ValidaUsuarioMesmaLista);                
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```